# C# ManagementObjectSearcher object container returns null for printers

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a strange issue, I hope somebody can help me out. A software was deployed without any problem 2 months ago. Now I got back to it, and it returns an invalid class error for the following code. All what it does, it returns all the printers installed on the computer.

The error is, the searcher.Container = null. In the past it was list of printer objects. Nothing has changed since then, the computer is a 64 bit Windows 7, using Visual Studio 2015.

```
public static ObservableCollection<PrinterStatusData> GetAvailablePrinterAndStatus()  
    {
        ObservableCollection<PrinterStatusData> printerStatus = new ObservableCollection<PrinterStatusData>();
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
        scope.Connect();

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

        foreach (ManagementBaseObject o in searcher.Get())
        {
            ManagementObject printer = (ManagementObject)o;
            if (printer != null)
            {
                string name = printer["Name"].ToString();
                bool available = !printer["WorkOffline"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true");
                    printerStatus.Add(new PrinterStatusData(name, available));
            }
        }

        return printerStatus;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (printer["Name"] != null)
                {
                    string name = printer["Name"].ToString();
                    bool available = !printer["WorkOffline"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true");
                    printerStatus.Add(new PrinterStatusData(name, available));
                }
```